# Which one is right: "allows to acquire" or "allows acquiring"?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which version of the following sentence is correct/better?

> "In particular, it **allows to acquire** a signal using a sample rate
>   significantly lower than the one dictated by the Nyquist criterion"

or

> "In particular, it **allows acquiring** a signal using a sample rate
>   significantly lower than the one dictated by the Nyquist criterion"

I searched Google Scholar for "[allows to acquire](http://bit.ly/T04nd3)" and "[allows acquiring](http://bit.ly/YbZEnI)", and it seems people use both more or less with the same frequency.

Comment: @AndrewLeach There have been quite a few questions today claimed at duplicates of that one. While I agree they are on the same territory, it also seems to me that none of them quite match the concerns in that one - not for example covering how a noun or pronoun could fix the first sentence here. Maybe we need a different gerund vs infinitive to rule them all.